# Laravel 5 proper searching and sorting mechanism

Tags: laravel, sorting, search, laravel-5

I create a Laravel 5.3 web application and had confronted with some difficulties with sorting and searching.

I have a table with some companies, which I get from a database. This table has several columns: Name, Industry, Country, etc. Table is sortable by clicking on the column header.

The Route for sorting is:

```
Route::get('/{sort?}/{order?}', 'CompaniesController@index')
->where('sort', 'id|name|country')
->where('order', 'asc|desc')
->name('companies');
```

Also I use `simplePaginate()` for paginating output results.

Url for the first page looks like:

`http://example.com/companies/id/desc` or `http://example.com/companies/country/asc`

and with pagination looks like
`http://example.com/companies/country/asc?page=2`

By this moment everything is working properly. But I also want to use HTML form for search by name, country, etc.

I tried to pass current url to `action` parameter and got this after submitting a form:

`http://example.com/companies/country/asc?name=test`.

I can work with this parameters and use them, but if I go to the second page using pagination I lost query string. I undestood that this way is wrong.

Next I tried to use Search Route:

```
Route::get('/search',['uses' => 'SearchController@getSearch','as' => 'search']);
```

with `SearchController` but I don't know how realise it properly.

I need combined usage of searching, sorting and pagination but I don't know how to include search parameters into the url for proper usage.

Thanx for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this package [jQuery DataTables API for Laravel 4|5](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

It Includes all the requirements you mentioned.

Comment: Thank for your answer! I will try this package.
But I thought that Laravel has native possibilities to realise these simple operations. isn't it?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial https://laracast.blogspot.my/2016/06/laravel-ajax-crud-search-sort-and.html